# Font shapes `TU/zpltlf/m/n' `TU/qhv/m/n' undefined

Tags: fontspec

Compiling this file with xelatex I see the following warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/zpltlf/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 20.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/qhv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 20.
```

What do I need to read to understand and fix this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext}

\usepackage[advantage,landau]{cryptocode}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Title}
\author{Paul Crowley}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract.
\end{abstract}

The advantage is at most $\advantage{f}{g}[(q, t')]$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: please add the example inline here not use an external link but `\usepackage{newpxtext}` is setting up 8bit fonts so not suitable for xelatex and Unicode (TU) encoding. You coul duse a real Palatino or the TeX-Gyre OpenType clone which are more naturally available as Unicode fonts

Comment: Why are you using XeLaTeX and load `newpxtext`? It's a package for pdflatex.

Comment: egreg: why do you say that? I can't find that in the README or documentation. What's the right way for me to get Palatino-like body text without changing my math font?

Comment: `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}` and `\usepackage{newpxmath}` (or you'd get Computer Modern for math that's incompatible with Palatino).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "incompatible" - you mean that if the math stays in Computer Modern the visual style is bad? I have to say I prefer it...